# WCF WebInvoke POST null for all parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I've been having trouble getting values in the parameters that I pass to my WCF service. They all show up as null when I use WebInvoke. However, I change  **WebInvoke**  in the following code to a **WebGet** (and after removing the bodystyle) I receive the values *correctly*, so I'm assuming that there is something wrong with my webinvoke code. From what I understand I need the bodystyle to be bare in order to pass primitive values rather than json objects.  I'm at a loss however, and have been trying to tinker with the configuration for hours.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant interface and call.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INLCInventory
{
[WebInvoke(
     Method="POST",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "AddItemToShrinkageReport?ReportID={ReportID}&ItemID={ItemID}&Calculated={Calculated}&Actual={Actual}&Shrinkage={Shrinkage}")]
    [OperationContract]

 void AddItemToShrinkageReport(string ReportID, string ItemID, string Calculated, string Actual, string Shrinkage);

}

public void AddItemToShrinkageReport(string ReportID, string ItemID, string Calculated,  
string Actual, string Shrinkage)
{
string test= ReportID;


}
```

And here is the relevant web.config section:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services >
  <service name="NLCInventory" >

    <endpoint contract="INLCInventory"  address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>


  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Finally, this is how I'm calling the web service with jquery.

```
function AddItemToShrinkageReport() {
Parameters = 'ReportID=' + ($('#lblUsageReportID').html()) + '&ItemID=' + $('#ddlItems').val() + '&Calculated=' + $('#txtCalculated').val() + '&Actual=' + $('#txtActual').val() + '&Shrinkage=' + $('#txtShrinkage').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/NLCInventory.svc/AddItemToShrinkageReport",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: Parameters,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using uritemplate before because that's what I saw on other stackoverflow answers to how to post to wcf parameters.  After doing some research I found out while it is possible,   **it is bad practice to do so.**  If you use parameters in the URL then you put your data at risk for interception-- when using https the URL is in plain/text and **is not** encrypted.  POST on the otherhand sends the 'data' to the body of the request which **is** subsequently encrypted when using https.

The changes I had to make in order to make it work were the following changes:

The UriTemplate is unnecessary, so for a post simply remove it.

The bodystyle also needs to be changed to wrapped-- otherwise it throws an error.

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
```

In my jquery ajax call i needed to change the data to JSON.  Like this:

```
data: '{"ReportID": "test", "ItemID": "test", "Calculated": "test", "Actual": "test", "Shrinkage": "test"}'
```

Content/Type tells the web server what kind of data you're sending it.  In my question I was essentially trying to send plain text while telling the server I was sending it JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

To be

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
```

Also I noticed extra brakets that may not be necessary here around $('#lblUsageReportID'.html():

```
Parameters = 'ReportID=' + ($('#lblUsageReportID'.html())
```

Comment: These changes don't have any effect unfortunately.  The parameters are still null when I step through the code after I made the changes.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DaneEdw The Uritemplate can be removed as well, it is defining a GET request while you want to make a POST request

Comment: When I remove the uritemplate the c# web service code doesn't get called. It seems like without it the web service doesn't work at all.

Comment: Your answer was mostly correct, I was just missing the JSON for my parameters after making your changes.